# How do I use JProgressBar to display file copy progress?

Tags: java, jprogressbar

I am working on a project that transfers files over a network and I want to incorporate a `JProgressBar` to show the progress during file transfer but I need help on that.

Comment: You should expand on what exactly you need help with. Is each file broken up into packets, or do you just know when each file is done transferring? Do you have the percentage, and just need help displaying? Do you have the file copy procedure already done?

Comment: community wiki?  Really?

Answer (score 3):

You probably would find a ProgressMonitorInputStream easiest, but if that doesn't do enough for you, look at its source code to get exactly what you want.

```
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                     new ProgressMonitorInputStream(
                              parentComponent,
                              "Reading " + fileName,
                              new FileInputStream(fileName)
                     )
                  );
```

To use a different transfer method then substitute an appropriate stream for FileInputStream.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be using a [`SwingWorker`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), as described in [this Core Java Tech Tip](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/making_progress_with_swing_s). See also [Using a Swing Worker Thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads2.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

....

public OutputStream loadFile(URL remoteFile, JProgressBar progress) throws IOException
{
    URLConnection connection = remoteFile.openConnection(); //connect to remote file
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); //get stream to read file

    int length = connection.getContentLength(); //find out how long the file is, any good webserver should provide this info
    int current = 0;

    progress.setMaximum(length); //we're going to get this many bytes
    progress.setValue(0); //we've gotten 0 bytes so far

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //create our output steam to build the file here

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;

    while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) //keep filling the buffer until we get to the end of the file 
    {   
        out.write(buffer, current, bytesRead); //write the buffer to the file offset = current, length = bytesRead
        current += bytesRead; //we've progressed a little so update current
        progress.setValue(current); //tell progress how far we are
    }
    inputStream.close(); //close our stream

    return out;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this will work.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at java nio channel to copy files.

Comment: FYI out.write(buffer, current, bytesRead) should be out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)

Answer (score 0):

Well [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) is a tutorial for JProgressBar, maybe that will help.